# Chartjs2: How to show multiple custom tooltips at the same time (while some of them should always be visible)?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using [chartjs](http://chartjs.org) to render Line charts.

To display a tooltip, I'm creating a **custom tooltip** as per the docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips

On hover, I can see the tooltip for a point as expected.

Now the requirement is:
1. Always show a fixed tooltip on a certain datapoint.
2. When the user hovers over some other data-point, the tooltip for this point should be shown while still showing the fixed tooltip defined in (1)

Is there a way to achieve this in Chartjs? (If not through its API, is there a non-conventional way?)